# How to export Subclipse SVN Repositories - Eclipse Juno, Subclipse 1.8.16

Tags: eclipse, svn, import, export, subclipse

I would like to import / export my SVN Repository locations from Subclipse 1.8.16 under Eclipse Juno. Is that possible?

I saw that if you are using the Subversive SVN plugin for Eclipse you can do something like this: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/SVNaction/location_ie.php

Is there any equivalent for Subclipse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can export your preferences from Eclipse and import them to a newer version including your svn locations. This is done by simply going to **File -> Export -> Select from General -> Preferences**. Then on the next step you can tick from a list the preferences you want to export. In this list, SVN preferences and SVN repositories should be included.

Then you can import these preferences to your new eclipse environment by doing File -> Import.. this time.

To make your transition smoother to your new eclipse environment you can also export the list of sites you used to download your plugins (like Subclipse etc). This is done by going to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites. You select the ones you want to export and then press the Export.. button. Then you can import them to your new eclipse by pressing in the same view the import button. Then, if you want in your new eclipse to install for example Subclipse, you can do it by going to Help -> Install new software... and then in the available software view there is a drop down menu from which you can select the corresponding software site.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but my problem is different:
If I try to export the Eclipse settings I do not have the SVN Repositories in the export list. here is a picture of my Export preferences wizard: http://i154.photobucket.com/albums/s242/tatacalu/StackOverflow/Eclipse%20SVN%20Repos%20Export/eclipse_export_preferences_svn_not_ok_zps80feab8b.png

However if I create a new Eclipse workspace and switch to it I have that option available: http://i154.photobucket.com/albums/s242/tatacalu/StackOverflow/Eclipse%20SVN%20Repos%20Export/eclipse_export_preferences_svn_ok_zpsfb885899.png

Comment: Hi @mikrohelen, the "SVN Preferences" and "SVN Repositories" are items specific for the Eclipse SUBVERSIVE client, not Subclipse [by Tigris.org].

Answer (score 0):

a bit late in the day but here goes.

Navigate to the dir WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core

In there there is a file '.svnProviderState'

This is a binary file but just copy this to the new location & Bob is your dad's brother.